# How can I possibly retrieve copyright issue from Youtube api?

Tags: youtube-api

I try to take some Youtube video information by using Youtube data:api.
Particularly, I'd like to know how to retrieve information of copyright piracy.
I checked the reference below. But I can't figure out how.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/

Does anyone know that?

Answer (score 3):

See [**this article**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos) for more details, but you can get a lot of information about a video, for example:

```
"contentDetails": { ... "licensedContent": boolean, ...
```

According to the doc, this field:

> Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means
>   that the content has been claimed by a YouTube content partner.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I'll check it out later!

Comment: For future readers, the `licensedContent` field is still false even for my videos with copyright issues. I'll leave a note/answer if I can find a solution.