# Get list copyrighted video in youtube

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When a video on Youtube was Includes copyrighted content flag in the video manager. I want get list that videos with some information such as "CONTENT","CLAIMANT","POLICY". What i would like to know is if Youtube's or Google's API can give us this same information?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [**`contentDetails.licensedContent`**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#contentDetails.licensedContent):

> Indicates whether the video represents licensed content, which means that the content was uploaded to a channel linked to a YouTube content partner and then claimed by that partner.

It is also provided in this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26085062/5995040), there is also no parameters who the claimant is or policy.

Hope this helps.